# Non-editable Work Item Type in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

Is there any possibility to create a custom Work Item Type in TFS 2010 that is read-only after the first save?

We would like to implement a very simple code review solution based on a custom review work item associated to a changeset.

The idea is that after the work item is created, it can not be altered afterwards (not even by the original creator).

I've tried setting the System.ChangeDate to FROZEN but that isn't supported and unfortunately the first save is also a change, so setting it to EMPTY or READONLY doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the community solution for code review for TFS 2010 http://teamreview.codeplex.com/

The most complete solution for Team System Code Reviews: a specific work item type and a Visual Studio add-in for a completely in IDE code review experience. TeamReview exploits the advantages of Team System and VSX to reduce waste and surface new business value from code reviews

HTH
Chees, Tarun

Comment: Yes, I've already seen TeamReview but it is way too complex for us. All we need is a non-changeable record linked to a changeset with a few fields.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the work item type's workflow. You can make changes to fields in both the states and the transitions.

You could try to modify the transition from **New** to **To Do** (or whatever the first state is called for your WI).

In those transitions, you can freeze or make read-only the fields that you want to freeze.

Hope this helps,
Assaf.

Comment: Is there a way though to make the Changeset linked unchangeable after creation of the Work Item?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your use case might be. The work item is created *before* the changeset is; You first create a work item, and only when you check the code in do you select the work item it is associated with. Normally, without extensive use of the TFS API, you can't change the changeset associated with the WI. Does this help you any?

Comment: Unfortunately deleting the link to the Changeset after it has been created is a matter of three clicks: if you open the Work Item, navigate to Links, select the Changeset and click Delete Link, the link gets removed.

Comment: Ah,  I see what you mean. Unfortunately, there is no rule, nor security setting that can deny the ability to alter links. What you *can* do, however, is to create a custom control that will deny the ability to modify links. It of course will work only if the control is installed on the users' machines. Also, you can create a server plugin that will **alert** you to the changes to WI links. If you really want, you could also probably revert such changes, from within the server plugin.